# canvas drag and drop when canvas is scaled

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have a canvas which I can zoom. Also, I have an object which I need to drag and drop. So, if you zoom canvas, objects will be positioned incorrectly. And even if I divide this by zoom factor like this

```
dragObject.x = (event.x - dragStartPosition.x) / canvasOffset.zoom;
dragObject.y = (event.y - dragStartPosition.y) / canvasOffset.zoom;
```

it is not working: it "jumps" instead of lagging behind mouse

---

This is my `redraw` function

```js
let redraw = () => {
    drawer.clear();
    drawer.canvas.save();    

    drawer.canvas.translate(canvasOffset.x, canvasOffset.y);
    drawer.canvas.scale(canvasOffset.zoom, canvasOffset.zoom);

    drawer.draw();

    drawer.canvas.restore();
}
```

And this is my `mousemove` handler

```js
canvas.onmousemove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    drawer.mousePosition = { x: event.x, y: event.y };

    if (draggingObject) {
        dragObject.x = event.x - dragStartPosition.x;
        dragObject.y = event.y - dragStartPosition.y;
    }
    
    if (mouseDown && !draggingObject) {
        const pos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
        const dx = pos.x - prevX;
        const dy = pos.y - prevY;

        if (prevX || prevY) {
            canvasOffset.x += dx;
            canvasOffset.y += dy;
            prevX = pos.x, prevY = pos.y
        }
    }

    redraw();
}
```

```
dragStartPosition = { x: event.x - dragObject.x, y: event.y - dragObject.y };
```

dragStartPosition is start position of mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally.
I changed `dragStartPosition` to

```js
dragStartPosition = { 
    x: (event.x * mouseScale - dragObject.x) - canvasOffset.x / canvasOffset.zoom, 
    y: (event.y * mouseScale - dragObject.y) - canvasOffset.y / canvasOffset.zoom
};
```

where `mouseScale = 1 + (1 / (canvasOffset.zoom / (1 - canvasOffset.zoom)))`

And drag:

```js
canvas.onmousemove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    drawer.mousePosition = { x: event.x, y: event.y };

    let mouseScale = 1 + (1 / (canvasOffset.zoom / (1 - canvasOffset.zoom)))

    if (draggingObject) {
        dragObject.x = ((event.x * mouseScale) - canvasOffset.x / canvasOffset.zoom) - dragStartPosition.x;
        dragObject.y = ((event.y * mouseScale) - canvasOffset.y / canvasOffset.zoom) - dragStartPosition.y;
    }
    
    if (mouseDown && !draggingObject) {
        const pos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
        const dx = pos.x - prevX;
        const dy = pos.y - prevY;

        if (prevX || prevY) {
            canvasOffset.x += dx;
            canvasOffset.y += dy;
            prevX = pos.x, prevY = pos.y
        }

        console.log("X: " + canvasOffset.x + ", Y: " + canvasOffset.y);
    }

    redraw();
}
```